# Only select top level row where non of the associated rows have a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a extraction of around 1000 rows where it breaks down an item into its components, I'm trying to only select the items where none of the description fields for the items row include the word deleted:

[image]

In this case i would only want to select item 2 and 4 from the table.

I've had a go but at my current point it i can only select parts of every item where one of the descriptions does not include the word, but i still get the rest of the items details which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.ItemNo = t.ItemNo 
        and 'Deleted' in (t1.ItemDescription, t1.PacketDescription, t1.ComponentDescription)
)
```

With an index on `(ItemNo, ItemDescription, PacketDescription, ComponentDescription)`, this should have good performance.

Or, in MySQL 8.0, you can do a window sum:

```
select *
from (  
    select 
        t.*,
        sum('Deleted' in (ItemDescription, PacketDescription, ComponentDescription)
            over(partition by ItemNo) sm
    from mytable t
    )
) t
where sm = 0
```

Comment: @LiamMorgan `WHERE (itemdescription LIKE '%deleted%' OR packetdescription LIKE.. ...)` This cannot use an index